# "UPDATE VERSIONED" HQL doesn't work for inherited entities (Grails 2.5.5)

Tags: hibernate, grails, optimistic-locking

I would like to use `UPDATE VERSIONED` HQL query for some hierarchical entities in my project. The reason is that I want to update a lot of rows in one query, but I also want optimistic locking mechanism to work.

I've prepared small example where the problem can be easily reproduced. I'm using Grails 2.5.5.

My domain classes:

```
abstract class Parent {

    String name

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {}
```

My test:

```
final def entity = new Child(name: 'Test').save()
final def version = entity.version
Parent.executeUpdate(
    'UPDATE VERSIONED Parent p SET p.name = :val WHERE p.id IN (:ids)',
    [ids: [entity.id], val: 'Updated value']
)
assertEquals(version + 1, entity.refresh().version)
```

The exception for H2 database:

```
Hibernate operation: could not prepare statement; bad SQL grammar [update parent set parent0_.version=parent0_.version+1, name=? where (id) IN (select id from HT_parent)]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PARENT0_" not found; SQL statement:
update parent set parent0_.version=parent0_.version+1, name=? where (id) IN (select id from HT_parent) [42102-176]
```

For Postgres I had similar exception which also clearly says that generated SQL query is wrong.

Here is the sandbox where you can try the code yourself: https://github.com/aistomin/gorm-update-versioned-bug

I suspect that it's not a Grails/GORM problem, but Hibernate itself doesn't allow me to do that.

Currently I switched to pure SQL and explicitly increment the version. It is working for me, but I'm just curios if somebody had the same problem. Maybe you can show me better workaround than I found. Or maybe I should not want this behaviour in the first place? :)

After all, I would like to know why it's not working? Is it somehow related to implicit joins which are forbidden in update HQL queries?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @vahid sorry, I'm not sure I clearly understand your solution. Answering your question: "When you create a child doesn't the parent automatically register the new entry considering table per hierarchy is false then everything is already in one table ?" - no, there are 2 tables: parent and child.

Comment: Sorry removed my comments since they were no use I think how you have it is correct according to here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html. Anyhow I found by tweaking it to be  `Parent.executeUpdate(
                            'UPDATE Parent p SET version = :version , p.name = :val WHERE p.id IN (:ids)',
                            [ids: [entity.id], val: 'Updated value',version:version+1]
                    )` works but then it is incrementing by version of child just created.. `VERSIONED` is for batched so unsure if that version would match real scenario